# Compare Source to Latest Record in Target

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I want to compare the records in the source table to the **latest** record (in each partition) in the target table

I have already accomplished this by creating a temporary view with the latest record in each partition in the target

Source:

```
id|name|salary|age  
------------------  
1|John|2500|25  
2|Mike|2500|30
```

Target:

```
id|name|salary|age|sdate  
------------------------  
1|John|1500|20|20190215  
1|John|2000|22|20190318
```

Get the latest record per partition in target and compare non-key columns to corresponding non-key columns in source:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW latest_rec AS
SELECT id, name, salary, age
FROM ( SELECT id, name, salary, age,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY sdate DESC) AS RN
       FROM target_tab) tt
WHERE tt.RN = 1
```

```
...
SELECT s.id, s.name, s.salary, s.age
FROM src_tab s
LEFT OUTER JOIN latest_rec t
ON s.id = t.id
AND MD5(s.name || s.salary || s.age) <> MD5(t.name || t.salary || t.age)
```

Expected Output:

```
id|name|salary|age|sdate  
1|John|1500|20|20190215  
1|John|2000|22|20190318
1|John|2500|25|20190525
2|Mike|2500|30|20190525
```

I was wondering if there were a better and smarter way to achieve the same functionality. Please let me know if additional information is necessary.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just use `join` and direct comparisons?

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, s.salary, s.age,
       t.id, t.name, t.salary, t.age
FROM src_tab s LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT id, name, salary, age,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY sdate DESC) AS RN
      FROM target_tab
     ) tt
     ON tt.id = s.id AND tt.RN = 1
WHERE (s.name <> t.name OR t.name IS NULL) OR
      (s.salary <> t.salary OR t.salary IS NULL) OR
      (s.age <> t.name OR t.age IS NULL) ;
```

This puts the comparisons in a single row.

Comment: Yes, that's right.. but just wanted to know if there is a smarter way to code this instead of this method ? Also, I am using MD5() to generate the hash of non-key columns and compare with the same in the target. On the other hand you example compares column to column. Which would be the best approach ?

Comment: @RishiChowdhury . . . Directly comparing the columns is better than using a hash.  Why worry about colissions?

Comment: Just wondering which one will be faster from a performance perspective (given 100 M record-sets) on either side.

Comment: @RishiChowdhury . . . Let's see, a hash has to read the column values and do complicated processing to convert them to a particular representation that might not do what you want (because of collisions).  Comparisons simply look at the values and compare them using built-in database function.  Direct comparisons are also logical, so -- for instance -- case might not matter for the name or trailing spaces might not matter.  This is not a place to use hashing.